# QtCharts in Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use QtCharts inside Qt 5.6. (I have no plans to install Qt 5.7/5.8 in the next months). Although I've found a Blog on the Qt site where Qt Charts add-in for At 5.6 is presented I did not find a download link. Has anyone any idea how to download Qt Charts lib and how to embed it inside Qt 5.6?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Qt 5.9
2. Copy the charts module over to Qt 5.6
3. Init a git repo in the module (you'll need it!)
4. Attempt a build of the module.
5. Fix bugs.
6. Goto 4 until you succeed.

You'll need to backport the module configuration - Qt 5.6 can't handle the .json file, and I'm not sure how much the Qt Quick Charts depends on new features in 5.8/9. You may wish to disable Qt Quick Charts at least initially to get the widget side working first.

Answer (score 2):

Kuba Ober's answer might help you, but beware of the licensing problem:

> ... the Qt Add-ons licensing will be changed so that the Qt Charts module
>   becomes available under both **GPLv3 and commercial** license terms.
>   http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/18/qt-charts-2-1-0-release/

So why not use [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) instead? With Qwt you have at least as much freedom as LGPL admits.